# Dynamic Column Headers working in Power Query but NOT on the Daschboard

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, powerquery, columnheader

I've been working with .xlsx files whose column headers change. As a result in Power Query I used Table.ColumnNames{1} to create dynamic headers that prevent me from getting an error when updating queries.
Despite no longer getting errors, dashboard is simply not working. whenever column names change, the matrixes and charts on the dashboard no longer recognize which columns were there.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try solution from Curbal canal

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUaVpgAdVGs